# Creating multiple Runtimes in same Liberty server MFP 8.0

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server, mobilefirst-cli

Based on the customer requirement we are trying to create 2 different Runtimes in the same liberty server.

Below products are being used,
1.WAS 8.5.5 Liberty 17.0.0.2
2. MFP 8.0

Please find the scenario tried, 
Scenario 1 :-
step 1 : Created databases sample1 and sample 2  and Created one server profile mfpserver in Liberty
step 2 : using Serverconfiguration tool tried to create first runtime configured using sample 1 successfully deployed.
step 3 : using Serverconfiguration tool tried to create second runtime configured using sample 2. It was failing with the error ***BUILD FAILED
/home/test/.mobilefirst_platform_server/server-configuration-tool/MobileFirst_Configuration_secondruntime/secondruntime.xml:106: The MobileFirst Server Artifacts is already installed with context root /mfp-dev-artifacts. It cannot be installed multiple times***

Scenario 2 :-
using ./mfpadm tool there is no commands for adding runtime. Is there any commands related to it?

Is there any other way where i can achieve this ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried with the server configuration tool. Since the server configuration tool runs every time as a new entry.

So if you see the samples, you can create your own tagging for the runtime and run the script successfully and you can see multiple runtimes in same server.

Answer (score 0):

Through Server Configuration Tool or ANT scripts only one runtime can be deployed. When attempting to deploy another , it throws the error you have seen.

However, you can deploy the runtime war file manually and make the necessary configurations - manually.

Comment: It is possible with the ant scripts, by creating a different taggings for second runtime. thanks